# How to Loop thru images on a Rails Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I am attempting to loop thru images for a game in a full rails application.  I have a table set up with information about each game, however when I attempt to do images I can only get one image to show on all the games instead of just iterating over each image in my image file to show the correct image against the correct game.
My images are currently stored in the public folder in my App...

```
.../Diverge/public/images
```

My current table ...

```
  <tbody>
    <% @games.each do |game| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= game.name %></td>
        <td><%= game.released %></td>
        <td><%= game.game_studio.name %></td>
        <td> <%= image_tag("/images/wc3.jpg", :size=> "300x200") </td> 
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', game %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

I attempted to do something like this to iterate over each image in the images folder

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="images">
  <% @images.each do |image| %>
    <%= image_tag image  %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

my controller

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 

  def index
    @games = Game.all
  end



  def show
  end

  def new
    @game = current_user.games.build
  end

  def edit
  end


  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.save
        format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.update(game_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 
  def destroy
    @game.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to games_url, notice: 'Game was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_game
      @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    end

    def game_params
      params.require(:game).permit(:name, :released, :game_studio_id, :game_id) 
    end
end
```

but nothing is rendering.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `image` is?

Comment: In your first example. you are only providing one image source "/images/wc3", so that's the only image that will ever show up. 
Can you provide the code for your Game model and Image model?  Are Images an attribute on Game or are they a separate model, associated with Game?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I only have a Game model that im trying to have images populate  ```class Game < ApplicationRecord
    include HTTParty
    belongs_to :game_studio
    has_many :reviews, through: :users
    has_many :users, through: :reviews
end
```

Comment: can you add that model code  to the question? 

I don't see how your images are stored anywhere - is `image` an attribute on `game`?  is the actual image stored in your /assets or /public folder? Or on S3?

Comment: So right now I just have it stored in the public folder ```.../Diverge/public/images```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use Dir.foreach to populate the @images variable on the controller methods that use it on the views:

```
@images = Array.new

Dir.foreach('/path/to/dir/for/images') do |image_filename|
  next if image_filename == '.' or image_filename == '..'
  @images.push image_filename
end
```